# Type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeerror, filestream, node.js-fs

I am trying to run the following code:

```
const uploadParams = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: '', Body: ''};
const file = '/home/a/bars/img1.png';

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('File Error', err);
});
uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
var path = require('path');
uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);
```

But I get the following error at `uploadParams.Body = fileStream;` line of the code:

```
Type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are assigning fileStream to a string when you declare the uploadParams object. `const uploadParams = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: '', Body: ''};` here. So, do `Body: null` in the initialization instead. Should get rid of the TS error. Or just do: `const uploadParams: {Bucket: string, Key: string, Body: ReadStream | string } = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: '', Body: ''};`

Comment: @Joel: Didn't work! Still get an error for `Body: ''` says `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReadStream'.ts(2322)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify what type the object-key `Body` can hold like this:

```
{ Bucket: string; Key: string; Body: string | ReadStream }
```

Solution:

```
import fs, { ReadStream } from "fs";
import path from "path";

const bucketName = '';
const uploadParams: { Bucket: string; Key: string; Body: string | ReadStream } = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: '',
  Body: '',
};
const file = '/home/a/bars/img1.png';

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('File Error', err);
});
uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);
```

Or if you use `require` you can use the `typeof` keyword:

```
// { Bucket: string; Key: string; Body: string | typeof ReadStream } 

const { ReadStream } = require("fs");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const bucketName = '';
const uploadParams: { Bucket: string; Key: string; Body: string | typeof ReadStream } = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: '',
  Body: '',
};
const file = '/home/a/bars/img1.png';

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('File Error', err);
});
uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);
```

Although I find it strange that you use an empty string to hold a stream. Why not just do?

```
const uploadParams: { Bucket: string; Key: string; Body: null | ReadStream } = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: '',
  Body: null,
};
```

[Demo - TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA3jASgUwIYBMDKUBOaC2MAvjALwx4COArgJZ4AUARAGYRMCUA3ALABQoSLDZkKyGvWTM2nXgPDQYAB1RQAFqKp1GTFetn9+gxQCNqwANbIoAOVT5kogORO5x2NSUAbEBgAKqDj2EABc8DAAQuZWUGHQOLRgAOZcMADSyACecbiJKZEg6Nkw8XkwAD4wUJlKyCAsSGhYuATEonD8MJHR1mFmltZ2DgA0nelZYS6jfF0RhcVT-ERuCsK0Xo7kTgD0aiAO26jbJoEQ27T4SQCMAHRKya6G8kIwLOvI2Hj2omw3wF9QZAoDCfAgMN4bbj8CEfFr2G7gBhOZA4HAgHBOYavahgYBQWjgGAMFE4EKoMCZDjwMbGEAbG4+JJIgBi7xgAFFUejMTASVC+ER+Z4fP5AsEbnMij93qD7HJhb50AEgvgIDcMplRHo1DcThBkGB7FIYfygA)